# haystack elasticsearch RealtimeSignalProcessor updates only "default" connection

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I have 3 search indexes and 3 haystack connections. I want the indexes to be updated in real time so I use RealtimeSignalProcessor. It is working only for 1 of the 3 connections ("default") but it does not work when I search for the term using the other 2 connections. Than I have to do python manage.py update_index manually to make it work.. How can this be fixed without updating the index manually?

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
        'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack',
    },
    'autocomplete_tags': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
        'INDEX_NAME': 'autcomplete',
         'EXCLUDED_INDEXES': ['entities.search_indexes.EntityIndex', 'allauth.search_indexes.UserIndex'],
    },
    'autocomplete_entities': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
        'INDEX_NAME': 'autocomplete_entities',
         'EXCLUDED_INDEXES': ['tags.search_indexes.TagsIndex', 'allauth.search_indexes.UserIndex'],
    }
}

HAYSTACK_SIGNAL_PROCESSOR = 'haystack.signals.RealtimeSignalProcessor'
```

Answer:

I figured that the reason why only the "default" connection was updated with the RealtimeSignalProcessor is the "INDEX_NAME". After I changed all 3 connection "INDEX_NAME" to "haystack" it works.

Answer (score -1):

I think your approach to elasticsearch is not right. You usually have one index and various types within that. If you follow that approach, all your Types should be automatically updated (hopefully).

Haystack is built with Solr in mind, I would suggest to use Solr. Haystack suggest terms like Index for a model you want to index but its actually a type in ElasticSearch. Looking at your HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS, you have created 3 indices instead of 3 types within an Index.

I have haystack working with Elasticsearch but it's a lot more work to tune it.

Comment: This answer is just wrong. "You usually have one index and various types" Haystack supports multiple indexes. "Haystack is built with Solr": Haystack is search index independent and is an abstract layer for a number of different search engine platforms.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr Yes and abstractions don't always play well. Looking at Haystack and not caring about the underlying Search solution is a foolish approach. But ofcourse, you are welcome to have your opinion.