# Is it possible to have multiple index in haystack elastic using real-time signal for auto-update

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I have multiple index in elastic using haystack I am trying to auto-update the index with RealtimeSignalProcessor. Is it supported by Haystack ?

Here is the [link](https://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v2.4.1/signal_processors.html#realtime-realtimesignalprocessor) I followed .
The same thing worked for single index very well.

I suspect the Haystack_connection in settings is something wrong. please suggest the correct syntax.

I don't have any specific need to write any Custom SignalProcessors. Is there a way to use off-the-shelve Haystack Realtime - RealtimeSignalProcessor
I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33001176/haystack-elasticsearch-realtimesignalprocessor-updates-only-default-connection)  question but was not helpful .

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE':        'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
    'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
    'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack',
    'INCLUDE_SPELLING': True,

},
'Hello':
{
    'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
    'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
    'INDEX_NAME': 'helloindex',
    'INCLUDE_SPELLING': True,
},
'Note':
{
    'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
    'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
    'INDEX_NAME': 'noteindex',
    'INCLUDE_SPELLING': True,
}, 
}
```

**Thank-you in advance.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Yes its possible](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v2.4.0/multiple_index.html)**

**I was able to solve this issue by using Django-Haystack's routers**

*In settings.py i did this*

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
'My_Testing':
{
    'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
    'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
    'INDEX_NAME': 'my_testing',
    'INCLUDE_SPELLING': True,
    'EXCLUDED_INDEXES': ['talks.search_indexes.NoteIndex'],

},
'Note':
{
    'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
    'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
    'INDEX_NAME': 'note',
    'INCLUDE_SPELLING': True,
    'EXCLUDED_INDEXES': ['talks.search_indexes.My_TestingIndex'],

},
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
    'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
    'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack',
    # 'INCLUDE_SPELLING': True,

},
}

HAYSTACK_ROUTERS = ['talks.routers.My_TestingRouter',
                'talks.routers.NoteRouter']

HAYSTACK_SIGNAL_PROCESSOR = 'haystack.signals.RealtimeSignalProcessor'
```

*and in routers.py file which is at same level as search_indexes.py add this*

```
    from haystack import routers


class My_TestingRouter(routers.BaseRouter):
    def for_write(self, **hints):
        return 'My_Testing'

    def for_read(self, **hints):
        return 'My_Testing'


class NoteRouter(routers.BaseRouter):
    def for_write(self, **hints):
        return 'Note'

    def for_read(self, **hints):
        return 'Note'
```

**Hope this helps somebody someday.**

peace.